# Best practice for Websocket authentification - Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Is there any ready to use Django Channels authentication method for the websocket client?

So far I did following, the client connects normally via websocket and the first message he should send is an authentification message:

import json
from channels import Group

```
def login(params, message):

    print "login"

    if "Username" in params and "Password" in params and "ApplicationName" in params:

        if params["Username"] == "dummy" and params["Password"] == "1234" and params["ApplicationName"] != "":

            message.reply_channel.send({"text":json.dumps({"authentification":"succeeded"})})

            return


    message.reply_channel.send({"text":json.dumps({"authentification":"unsucceeded"})})
    message.reply_channel.send({"close": True})
```

routing.py

```
from . import consumers
from channels import route

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', consumers.ws_connect),
    route('websocket.receive', consumers.ws_receive),
    route('websocket.disconnect', consumers.ws_disconnect),
]
```

consumers.py

```
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):

    text = message.content.get('text')
    dict = json.loads(text)

    if "connect" in dict:

        login(dict["connect"], message)
```

Comment: How did you solve this?